# How to use the same field several times in Jide Pivot Table?

Tags: java, swing, pivot-table, jide

I found, that I can use each field only once in Jide Table. For example, if I counted mean over some field I am unable to count sum over the same field.

Is it possible to overcome?

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of Jide PivotTable with field panel opened ar right:

[image]

As you see, fields, taken from fields panel and dragged to data area or row area, are disappeared from fields panel. This means that any field can exist only in one area.

The same implies from API method [`PivotField#setAreaType()`](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/pivot/PivotField.html#setAreaType(int)), which has scalar argument. I.e. one field can be assigned to only one area type.

This caused me to duplicate field `Region Area` 4 times in underlying source: one for value, one for mean, one for min, one for max.

Simultaneously, the wish to have same field counted several times with different aggregation function looks general and it is strange, if PivotTable does not allow this out of the box.

Comment: Can you add code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @user1803551 see my update please